# Mail.app disconnected from data files

Tags: macos, mac, mail.app, email, user-account

My mac mini was acting up, so I reset the Nvram and ran the disk utilities from recovery mode.  The mini started up fine and runs stable, but now my mail, calendar, and contacts have been wiped clean.  Mail wants me to start fresh.  Its as if the user profile is no longer connected to the library/data/metadata.  I can see the mail accounts in the library folder, but I cannot reconnect.  iTunes and Photos were not affected.  Only Mail, Calendar, Contacts.  I have an SSD system drive and a separate internal drive for my home folder.  Apple support had me reset and move my home drive to the SSD restart, and back move it back again to the second drive to see if it would reconnect, but no change.  Mail won't even give me the option of using the connection doctor, just set up new account or quit.

There has to be a way to reconnect my user profile with the data files that i can plainly see in the library folders.

Anybody ever heard of such an occurrence?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Downvoted for title.

Answer (score 1):

I am wondering if you take the actual mail files out of your ~/Library folder (drop them on the desktop) and then re-create your mail account(s), username, passwords, servers and the like you should then be able to import those files sitting on your desktop into the new accounts you just recreated.

It certainly won't answer the question what happened but will solve the more prosaic issue of not having access to your archived email.

Answer (score 0):

Check that the account is set to the Home folder you think it ought to be...

System Prefs > Users & Groups > [unlock] > Right click your account & select Advanced...

Make sure the Home directory is as it should be.
Don't change anything else.

Add a comment if that doesn't fix it.

Comment: Yes, it is the correct Home directory.

Comment: Checked and double checked it...

Answer (score 0):

You don’t need move anything from Mail folders, it will import from them just fine,